# RewriteRule giving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having trouble in RewriteRule its giving me 500 Internal Server Error bellow is my code in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^About-Us.php$ page.php?title=About Us [NC,L]
```

And here is my server php info link you can check if there is something need to do from my hosting.

```
http://travelinsure.ca/seo_links.php
```

Any suggestions please ?

Many Thanks,
Sonu Ahmad

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to see what is causing 500 error.

Comment: Sorry but how can I check my Apache error.log ?

Comment: That I can't tell since path is different on each host. You need to ask your server admin guys.

Comment: I am unable to find error.log on my hosting. I am using godaddy hosting with parallels panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between `About` and `Us`, which is making mod_rewrite interpret it as a delimiter for the "rewrite flags". Try escaping it:

```
RewriteRule ^About-Us.php$ page.php?title=About\ Us [NC,L]
```